# Performance using docker inside lxc

Tags: server, docker, lxc

Is it good to have docker container inside lxc? How about running php, mysql application performance using docker container inside lxc for this when compare to running this applications as service in lxc container?

Comment: Docker inside LXC? That sounds really unnecessary to me. Why not just run Docker containers?

Comment: Containers are not Virtual Machines; they generally use kernel features instead of emulation (which is much more intensive). As long as you are not trying to emulate a different environment or architecture, the performance penalty of a Container should be quite minor.